# Flashing message doesn't work but errors does

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect someone back with a success message.
The admin fills in a form to create a new user, and when the form isn't filled in correctly, the validator sends the user back with an error message that shows. But when I manually want to send back someone with a success message the message doesn't show up.

**message.blade.php**

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{$error}}
    </div>
@endforeach
@endif

@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif

@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       {{session('error')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

and this is where I send the user back with a success message:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('generate')){
        $request->merge(['password' => $this->randomPassword()]);
        $request->merge(['password_confirmation' => $request->password]);
    }

    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'email' => 'required|max:255|string|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed'
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);

    if($request->has('generate')){
        return back()->with('succes', 'Password:' . $request->password);
    }

    return back()->with('succes', 'User created');
}
```

Only the error message created by the validator do show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in your controller, should be `success`, not `succes`

```
 if($request->has('generate')){
        return back()->with('success', 'Password:' . $request->password);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'User created');
```